# Getting an md-select option list in selenium

Tags: java, angularjs, selenium

I have a `md-select` dropdown WebElement. I can get it's `md-options` by doing:

```
List<WebElement> dropDownElements = myDropDown.findElements(By.tagName("md-option"));`
```

This gets me a list of `md-options`. The list has my expected number of items.
However, I want to verify the text in these `md-options` are correct.  The value attribute of each of those WebElements is `[object Object]`, and I want the actual text.

By traversing the fields of the web element, I see that the `firstChild_` of the `firstChild_` 's `data_` field has the actual text i'm looking for (with a lot of white space padding). It's in a `DomText` object. But, the API doesn't have any kind of `getChild()`, and I think that's clunky anyways?

How can I easily get to the text contents of the `md-options`? Would xpath allow me to get what I want? How would I do that query?

HTML:

```
<md-input-container class="my-container" flex-gt-sm>
    <label>Some Label</label>
    <md-select ng-model="myCtrl.selectedItem" required id="myDropDown">
        <md-option ng-value="selectedItem"
                   ng-repeat="selectedItem in myCtrl.itemList">
            {{selectedItem.thing1 + ': ' + selectedItem.thing2}}
        </md-option>
    </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

Comment: can you share your HTML code?

Comment: What do you get when you read the attribute value of an option?:
In c#: 
IWebElement firstOption = dropDownElements[0];
var valueOfFirstOption = firstOption.GetAttribute("value");

Comment: HTML added. @KoenMeijer, when I do that, I get [object, Object] as the text. I also tried selecting the md-select to expand the items, but that seems to have no effect on getting the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created this helper method to get teh string values for a given mdSelect

```
public static List<String> getStringsInMdSelect(WebElement mdSelect) {
    List<String> selectionStrings = new ArrayList<>();
    WebElement contentElement = mdSelect.findElement(By.tagName("md-content"));
    List<WebElement> contentDivs = contentElement.findElements(By.tagName("div"));

    for (WebElement contentDiv : contentDivs) {
        String rawText = contentDiv.getAttribute("textContent");
        selectionStrings.add(rawText.trim());
    }
    return selectionStrings;
}
```